# sqlite increase size of returned blob

Tags: c, sqlite

I was wondering whether it is possible to tell SQLite to return the blobs in memory chunks that are multiples of 4 let's say.

For various reasons this would make other parts of the code simpler.

I'm using the C-API function

```
const void *sqlite3_column_blob(sqlite3_stmt*, int iCol);
```

Comment: You can always memcpy into a padded buffer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such function; pointers returned by SQLite point into buffers that may be part of larger data structures.

If you want the larger buffers hard enough, you have to create your own copies.

Answer (score 0):

You can [open a BLOB for incremental I/O](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/blob_open.html) and [read](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/blob_read.html) portions of its data. Finally you should [close BLOB](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/blob_close.html).

Comment: How is `sqlite3_blob_open`/`read` any simpler than just copying the return value of `sqlite3_column_blob`?

Comment: The question was not about simplicity.